# How to convert this htaccess to iis web.config?

Tags: .htaccess, iis

Why when i convert .htaccess automatically with IIS web.config via IIS Manager > Rewrite URL this show me 404 error

How to convert this manually to web.config?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(install)($|/) - [L]
    RewriteRule ^$ app/webroot/ [L]
    RewriteRule (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

This is the result using IIS Manager (web.config)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 1" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(install)($|/)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="None" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/webroot/" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="Imported Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/app/webroot/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the Sub-status code of 404 error? Because 404.0 and 404.19 is different error. You could find it in C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles.

It looks like the rule has been transformed correctly.

Rule1 will scan incoming URL **domain.com/install/** or **domain.com/install** and prevent these URL from being rewritten.

Rule2 will rewrite  **domain.com** to **domain.com/app/webroot/**

Rule3 will rewrite Any incoming rule for example. **domain.com/a.aspx** to **domain.com/app/webroot/a.aspx**.

So are these rules achieve your requirement?

To promise rewrite could be processed without ensure

1.Please ensure the request has been delivered to your IIS server. Sometimes networking issue would route the request to another server and return 404 error.

2.Please ensure the target URL like domain.com/app/webroot/ or domain.com/app/webroot/(.*) can be accessed without any issue.